# Why some azure service bus message go to Deadletter queue without any error in kubectl log?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, message-queue, servicebus, azure-aks

I checked Azure AKS log by `kubectl logs <-POD->` which I log the message ID at the beginning when start to handle it. However, there was no log to log down a few messages which went to Deadletter suddenly. I tried to put them to normal queue again but faced similar result.

Why is it happening? How to solve it?

Below is log that I can see sometimes but it should be also resume processing messages after a period of time. (I ran 4 pods in parallel)

```
    Error for serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage()
    Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
    <BODY><h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
    <hr><p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
    </BODY></HTML>
        at Function.ServiceClient._normalizeError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/serviceclient.js:757:12)
        at ServiceBusService.ServiceClient._processResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/serviceclient.js:455:41)
        at Request.processResponseCallback [as _callback] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/serviceclient.js:213:35)
        at Request.self.callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
        at Request.emit (events.js:203:13)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
        at Request.emit (events.js:203:13)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be hitting into a [transient exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions). On such errors, you could setup an retry with a backoff until it succeeds.

I believe in most cases such errors should resolve in a couple of retries unless there is a major problem with the service at the time.